# My Libgdx exported .jar build doesn't open

Tags: java, libgdx

when i exported my Libgdx project into a runnable jar file and run it he wouldn't open and when i open it with cmd i got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:466)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:433)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:586)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
```

i looked everywhere and i don't found nothing, what this can be?
*sorry for the spelling errors*

Comment: The missing `ApplicationListener` class is part of the libGDX library. If you want a "one click" runnable fat jar, this class (any all other dependencies) have to be included in your jar. Provide additional information how you build the jar. Check the jar content (which is a simple zip file). It should contain the file: `com\badlogic\gdx\ApplicationListener.class`

Comment: How did you export your project into the jar file? You should export it using the gradle build script, that was genereated by the libGdx project generator. Then gradle will make sure, all dependencies are added to the jar file.